# pg_query('\d') is not working in PHP

Tags: php

Now I'm doing to take database(Postgres) backup using php. I'm using command pg_query('\d') to retrive tables. But is not working. Please help me.

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? What happens?

Answer (score 2):

`\d` is a feature of the `psql` command line tool. It is not available in queries.

Comment: \d is equivalent for php query?

Answer (score 1):

From [bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/172978-sql-command-list-tables)

> If you start psql with the -E option
>   you can see the internal commands sent
>   to the backend. This can often give
>   you a lot of hints as to the best way
>   to pull catalog data from a db:

```
jason=# \dt
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
c.relname as "Name",
CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'i' THEN
'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' END as "Type",
u.usename as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_user u ON u.usesysid = c.relowner
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','')
AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;
**************************
```

This way, you can see what query is actually used when you use `\d` in console client. When working from PHP, you have to use that query instead of `\d`. You can also get equivalent queries for other commands in this way.

Answer (score 0):

\d works in psql. If you want to do this on the web server, you can probably use:

```
Select tablename From pg_tables Where tableowner='theowner';
```

And of course, change "theowner" to the name of whomever the owner actually is.